# Supplying power to op-amp using Via

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, control, pcb-layers

In my PCB, I am bringing voltage source through the bottom-layer and connected to the supply pin of op-amp on top-layer using via (Drill diameter - 0.3mm) as shown in the figure below.
[image]

I have doubt that what if the opamp need more current than rated for via. I don't know about the rated current of via either. Is it good practice to do this? and is the via filled with conducting material or hollow just like a through-hole pad?

Comment: A 0.3mm via on a 1.6mm PCB allows at least 1A, so no problem. If it was a problem then we couldn't design 4, 8 or 16 layer PCBs. BTW, make sure the supply is well-regulated and filtered, and the decoupling caps are placed near to the supply pins.

Comment: It looks like you could extend the track northwards under the IC and add several vias.